# UnrecognizedPropertyException not making sense to me

Tags: java, json, jackson

I have a JSON map that contains a simple data type (String) and a complex data type. I have created a struct to handle this. Here it is:

```
public static class PayloadData {
    String authkey;
    PizzaPlaceTo pizzaPlace;
    Map<String, List<String>> updates;
}
```

Now, I read the data in like this:

```
    PayloadData payloadData = objectMapper.readValue(payload, PayloadData.class);
```

and it's giving me:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.UnrecognizedPropertyException: Unrecognized field "authkey" (class pizzainthecloud.pizzaplace.controller.PizzaPlaceController$PayloadData), not marked as ignorable (0 known properties: ])
 at [Source: {"authkey":"Don't Panic!","pizzaPlace":{"contactName":null,"customerId":null}; line: 1, column: 13] (through reference chain: pizzainthecloud.pizzaplace.controller.PizzaPlaceController$PayloadData["authkey"])
```

So if I'm reading this correctly, it's telling me there's no authkey in my receiving class to receive the authkey in the JSON data, right? Only there is.

Help, please.

Comment: maybe is because you are using a `String` object, not a primitive `string`, so you need to initialize the String `new String("Don't Panic")` (this is a shot in the dark, I can be totally wrong...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, it looks like that Jackson only works with beans and not with struct style classes. I changed my class to:

```
public static class PayloadData {
    private String authkey;
    private PizzaPlaceTo pizzaPlace;
    private Map<String, List<String>> updates;

    public String getAuthkey() {
        return authkey;
    }

    public void setAuthkey(String authkey) {
        this.authkey = authkey;
    }

    public PizzaPlaceTo getPizzaPlace() {
        return pizzaPlace;
    }

    public void setPizzaPlace(PizzaPlaceTo pizzaPlace) {
        this.pizzaPlace = pizzaPlace;
    }

    public Map<String, List<String>> getUpdates() {
        return updates;
    }

    public void setUpdates(Map<String, List<String>> updates) {
        this.updates = updates;
    }
}
```

And that resolved the problem.